# fgets() function in C

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, libc

I know everybody has told me to use fgets and not gets because of buffer overflow. However, I am a bit confused about the third parameter in `fgets()`.  As I understand it, fgets is dependent on:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

`char* str` is the ptr to where my input will be stored.

`num` is the max number of character to be read.

but what is `FILE *stream`?  If I am just prompting the user to enter a string (like a sentence) should I just type "`stdin`" ?

And should I type `FILE *stdin` at the top, near `main()`?

Answer (score 17):

You are correct.  `stream` is a pointer to a `FILE` structure, like that returned from `fopen`.  `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are already defined for your program, so you can use them directly instead of opening or declaring them on your own.

For example, you can read from the standard input with:

```
fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
```

Or from a specific file with:

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
fgets(buffer, 10, f);
```

Comment: I think the second parameter should be strlen(buffer) -1. Unless you buffer is a 11 bytes.

Comment: @robUK, that would only work if the buffer weren't all zeros to begin with.  As the OP mentioned, buffer overflows aren't really the concern of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should just use `stdin`. That is a predefined `FILE *` that reads from the standard input of your program. And it should already be defined if you have a `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your file (which you'll need for `fgets`).

Answer (score 3):

Broadly there are two ways you can communicate with files in C. One is using the low-level OS dependent system calls such as `open()`, `read()`, `write()` etc which work with file descriptors. Another one is using `FILE` structures which are used in C library functions like `fread()`, `fwrite()` etc including the one you mentioned above.

As it is with the UNIX philosophy, everything is a file. So even the standard input (`stdin`) is treated as a pointer to a `FILE` structure.

tl;dr Yes, you should use `stdin` for `FILE* stream` in your call to `fgets()`

Answer (score 1):

FILE is the standard C file.  Yes, if you want to read from standard input, [stdin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stdin/) is the correct symbol.